# How to find the number of non-empty column in some rows of a CSV file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

CSV file looks like Excel, which has 4 columns: Stu_ID and completed date , Stu_ID and cancelled date. I would like to count the number of non-empty rows of those student who has completed application and also who didn't. After than I would like to make a ratio.

Comment: Can you please post an example of your data